# Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed - Issues connecting Raspberry Pi Zero to Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 Via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I currently have a Raspberry Pi Zero with the latest version of Raspian installed and a [Pi Camera V2.1](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-camera-module-v2-1-with-mount) and a [RedBear IoT pHat](https://redbear.cc/product/iot-phat.html) connected, both of which are functioning correctly - by correctly I mean the camera successfully takes photos and the pHat enables the Pi to connect to WiFi and to my iPhone via Bluetooth.

I am attempting to take a photo with the Pi Camera and transfer it via Bluetooth to a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2.

As previously mentioned, I can successfully connect the Pi to my iPhone via Bluetooth, although after a bit of research, I discovered that iOS does not allow file transfer via Bluetooth (please correct me if I am wrong). For this reason, I am now trying to connect to a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 via Bluetooth. The devices successfully pair, however they will not connect and the following error message appears on the monitor connected to the Pi:

> Connection Failed -
>   GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Failed: No such file or directory. Try to connect 
>   manually.

After this, I attempted to connect the devices via the command line, like so:

```
pi@raspberrypi: ~ $ sudo bluetoothctl
```

This returns the MAC address of the Samsung Tab.

```
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
[bluetooth]# trust 11:22:33:44:55:66
[bluetooth]# pair 11:22:33:44:55:66
[bluetooth]# connect 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Everything works as it should do up until the last line when following error message is returned:

> Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed

Does anyone have an idea of how I might solve this issue and get the Pi to connect to the Samsung Tab so that I can transfer image files from the Pi to the Tab?

I hope I have included enough information.